# Doe we have any algorithm to optimise a Boolean expression

Tags: algorithm, compiler-optimization, compiler-construction

Let's say we have an expression like:

```
(Rule1 && Rule2 && Rule3)
```

Where `Rule1`, `Rule2` and `Rule3` are `REST` calls that return true or false.

I would like to optimise the REST calls depending on the expression.
In the example quoted, if one of the rules breaks, there is no need to evaluate others.

In case of `(Rule1 || Rule2 || Rule3)`
I would like to fire all at once or try to get the first true and then ignore others.

This is how compilers evaluate boolean expressions. If I had to implement this in Java or any modern programming language, do we have any standard algorithm for this?

Comment: For `&&`: Evaluate rule 1. If it's false, stop. Else evaluate rule 2. If it's false, stop. Etc. What more of an algorithm do you need?

Comment: What I meant is say if have a complex expression like (Rule1 && (Rule2 || Rule3))&&Rule4, Here I would evaluate Rule4 first , then go for others. Do we have any standard paradigms to evaluate expressions that assigns priorities to each individual expression  and then start evaluating one by one

Comment: In general a execution plan for such problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most modern languages support [short-circuit evaluation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), evaluating the second argument only if the first argument doesn't determine the whole expression.  So in `(Rule1 && Rule2 && Rule3)` Rule2 will not be evaluated if Rule1 is false.  Likewise in `(Rule1 ||Rule2 || Rule3)`
Rule2 will not be evaluated if Rule1 is true.

The convention for determining "first argument" is left-to-right.  This is because most modern programming languages still follow western rules of writing.  So the "algorithm" to minimize wasted cycles is:

- for boolean AND the leftmost argument should be the one most likely to be false, the second argument the next most likely to be false, and so on
- for boolean OR the leftmost argument should be the one most likely to be true, the second argument yadda yadda

How can we decide which argument is the most likely to be false?  By using our skill and judgement, based on the information we have about the system.  Or guessing if we don't have enough information.  This can be an area prone to [premature optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization).

Finally, to address this:

> if have a complex expression like `(Rule1 && (Rule2 ||
>   Rule3))&&Rule4`, Here I would evaluate Rule4 first

You need to write the expression as

```
(Rule4 && Rule1 && (Rule2 || Rule3))
```